# Null value when passing value from ajax to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a value that I want to pass to MVC action,

here is the JS side

```
function functionName(Name) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetName",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",  
            data:JSON.stringify({ 
                Name: Name
            }),
            success: function (mydata) {

            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

and here is my action

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetName(string Name)
{
       return Json(new { oid = Name});
}
```

Noting that I successfully print the value "Name" before I send it to the action, but the action is receiving it as a "null"

Comment: Just use `data: { Name: Name }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke when to use Stringify and when not?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, OP could have used `data:JSON.stringify({ Name: Name }),` but then the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` also needs to be set (the default is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`)

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke for the explanation, can you also tell me difference between **contentType** and **dataType** ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad,  `contentType` is the format that the client sends to the server. `dataType` is the format that's sent back from the server.

Comment: i was also thinking that but needed to clear it @StephenMuecke once again thanks

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, You raise an interesting issue about when to use JSON.stringify() (in conjunction with `contentType`) or not and I have been trying to find a good resource but can't. Personally I don't use it (because  I have never really had to) but there are some situations where it is necessary (e.g.sending arrays of objects and opposed to name/value pairs where the name includes a indexer)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i did'nt thought that it could be interesting but as you are saying so i think it is interesting, do let me know when you find resource of it..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stephen "in the comments" is correct
the solution is
changing this

```
data:JSON.stringify({ 
                Name: Name
            }),
```

to

```
data: { Name: Name }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding

```
contentType: "application/json"
```

as belove

```
 function functionName(Name) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/GetName",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",  
        contentType: "application/json",
        data:JSON.stringify({ 
            Name: Name
        }),
        success: function (mydata) {

        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Hope this will help you, :)